# File.Move error in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying a simple move as shown below and get the following error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(srcFile);
if (file1.Exists)
{
 FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(destFile);
 if (!file2.Exists)
 {
  try
  {
   File.Move(srcFile, destFile);
  }
  catch (System.IO.IOException e)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you creating or opening file1 from within your code?  If so, you'll need to close the FileStream before attempting the move.

Comment: Thanks - this was the problem. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

The error means that the file is in use:

- either by your application (you need to close the file in order to be able to move it)
- or by another application. There isn't much you can do here, but retry later.

Answer (score 3):

Check with [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which process holds the file open.

Answer (score 2):

Use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out which process is using the file and handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch this exception, you can try calling the Windows API [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(v=VS.85).aspx), with the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag. This will move the file the next time you reboot; this is want installers normally do when they detect a locked file. You need to be admin or LocalSystem for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Unlocker to see file locks. It will help you to figure out the problem.

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Answer (score 0):

maybe open the file1 in your code before you move it and don't close the filestream